# Wordpress Option Pages Multiple Permissions

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have a word press options page and I want to make it view-able for all users who are an editor or above. My code is the following:

```
add_menu_page('example', 'example', 'editor', __FILE__, array('example', 'example'));
```

I have tried pasting that multiple times with different user roles each time, and even separating each user role with a comma but that does not work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, use

```
if(current_user_can('editor')){
    add_menu_page(..., 'editor', ....);
}elseif(current_user_can('someotherrole')){
    add_menu_page(..., 'someotherrole', ....);
}
```